# delete query isnot working in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

following is the code i have wriiten in model and calling this function in controller.
i have tried 3 different ways to delete the record but none of them is working.
while calling this function it display deletingbut did not deleting the record.

```
function deleteRecord($id, $componentName, $action)
{
    try{
        echo 'deleting';
        $this->deleteAll($id); 
        //$this->delete(['id' => $id]);
        //$this->query("DELETE FROM `ebay_leave_feedback_queues` WHERE `id`= 983");
     }catch(Exception $e){
            $returnArray = array( // creating an array to log msg 
                'Ack' => 'Error',
                'ErrorCode' => '122456',
                'Message' => $e->getMessage(),
                'TraceOfException' => $e->queryString,
                'RowId' => 'Component: /Controller/Component/' . $componentName . ', Function: ' . $action . ', Table: =feedback_queues, Row Id: ' . $id
            );
            App::import('Model', 'SystemErrorLog'); 
            $SystemErrorLog = new SystemErrorLog();
            $SystemErrorLog->writeLog($returnArray, $componentName, $action);
     }
     return true;
}
```

please tell me if i have written something wrong
you help will be appreciated.

Comment: $this->delete($id); or $this->deleteAll(array('id' => $id));

Comment: I have tried your code too.But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, you swapped the functions for deleteAll() and delete():

delete() takes an ID (assuming your model has a primary key set which is labeled 'id' or defined on in the model); it is intended to delete a single record.

deleteAll() takes an array with conditions; it's use is to delete multiple records based on these conditions.

So it is either:

```
delete($id);
```

or

```
deleteAll(['id' => $id]);
```

The latter is a bit overkill in this case, though.

However, the question remains: why are adding this function as you can call delete() directly from the controller?

Comment: i have tried   $this->delete($id); and $this->deleteAll(['id' => $id]) but these are also not working

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling this from the controller, you need to use the following:

```
$this->Model->delete($id);
```

Make sure to replace Model with your model name.